# While running numpy I get errors

Tags: python, numpy, keras

While running numpy and the rest of all the code I keep getting an error

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

print(train_labels[0])
```

I got an error saying this:

```
C:\Users\Martijn\Anaconda3\envs\Neural\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550:
 FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated;
 in a future version of numpy,
 it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. You should still get your result. If you don't see anything, it's probably `None`, you can check that with `print (repr(train_labels[0]))`

Comment: Yeah okay it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error-- it's a warning. Therefore, it will not hinder the performance of your code.

You can ignore it for now, as it is something that TensorFlow engineers must address.